# duplicated object when rendering

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

i'm almost through a tutorial by " Andrew Price " and after i finished the modeling and texturing [image: Solid]

But when i rendered the Design i found out that the third small rail got duplicated i don't know why !

[image: rendered]

Answer (score 1):

Look in the Outliner, you probably have an object whose visibility is disabled for the viewport (eye icon) but enabled for rendering (camera icon)

[image]

Or you have a duplicated object in a layer that is not visible on the 3D viewport but is renderable.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have objects, geometry or layers hidden, but active for rendering.

1.) Check for the layers. If a layer has a dot inside it's icon, activate it and look if object on this layer

2.) Press ALT+h in the 3D viewport and see if object appears

3.) Go in to EDIT mode (tabulator key) of every rail (and maybe other objects) and press ALT+h to see if the geometry appears

4.) Check the outliner like cegaton suggested